# Giving feedback for invalid JSON input

Tags: json, go

I have this code that gives feedback to the user for specific issues in JSON such as missing commas etc. It doesn't give the right line number though if the issue is at the end of a line, for example a missing comma. It tells you the next line. How can I fix this?

```
decoder := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input))
decoder.UseNumber()

var err error
line, character := 1, 1

for {
    if _, err = decoder.Token(); err != nil {
        break
    }
}

if err != nil {
    if err == io.EOF {
        fmt.Println("JSON is valid")
    } else {
        jsonLines := strings.Split(input, "\n")
        cumulativeCharCount := 0
        for i, lineContent := range jsonLines {
            cumulativeCharCount += len(lineContent) + 1
            if cumulativeCharCount >= int(decoder.InputOffset()) {
                line = i + 1
                character = int(decoder.InputOffset()) - (cumulativeCharCount - len(lineContent) - 1)
                fmt.Printf("JSON is invalid at line %d, character %d: %v\n", line, character, err)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you try to detect when these circumstances occur?  If you can solve that, fixing the result is easy.

Comment: Wrap your strings.NewReader(input) in a transparent reader that keep track of line numbers etc. Note that you probably cannot "fix" that as the _detection_ of an error might not happen _where_ the underlying typo is (albeit near by).

Comment: @Volker yeah, i was worried about that too. do you have advice for another way to go about this? would really appreciate it

Comment: Instead of trying to print an inaccurate position, print the last X bytes before (and including the issue) to show the user the issue.